# Using CSOM, How to check-out a list item?

Tags: list, csom, item, check-in

I want to update a list item in a list with versioning enabled on it. I should check out item before update, update it , and then check it in. I find CSOM code for Check in/out a file in a document library, but no code found to check out/in a list items. For a document library we should use this code:

```
...
ctx.Load(items, item=> item.Include(f => f.File)); 
if(item.File.CheckOutType == CheckOutType.None){
// Do stuff...
}
```

but for a list item this code is not valid.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this the code you are looking for? https://www.codesharepoint.com/csom/get-check-out-type-of-file-in-sharepoint-using-csom and this one 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/663695/force-checkout-documents-library-in-sharepoint-onl